# Raspberry Pi 4B connect to WPA2-Enterprise Wifi Network but loss Ethernet cable connection

Tags: raspbian, ethernet, wpa-supplicant, dhcpcd

I'm trying to connect to the university wifi (WPA2-Enterprise). I do the following modifications on files and successfully connect to the network. However, the Ethernet cable connection is disabled and I get an error on dhcpcd when I reboot the system.
Here are the modifications:
In `/etc/network/interface`, I add the following lines

```bash
auto lo
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
 pre-up wpa_supplicant -B -D wext -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
 post-down killall -q wpa_supplicant
```

In `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`, I add the following lines at the end

```bash
interface wlan0
env ifwireless = 1
env wpa_supplicant_driver = wext, nl80211
```

At last, I add the wifi connection info to `/etc/wpa_applicant/wpa_applicant.conf`

```bash
network={   
    ssid="eduroam"
    priority=1
    proto=RSN
    key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
    pairwise=CCMP
    auth_alg=OPEN
    eap=PEAP
    identity="myusername"
    password="mypassword"
    phase1="peaplabel=0"
    phase2="auth=MSCHAPV2"
}
```

After doing these, Pi can successfully connect to the network.
But I got the following error message in `dhcpcd.service` and the Ethernet is disabled.

```bash
Warning: The unit file, source configuration file or drop-ins of dhcpcd.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.
● dhcpcd.service - dhcpcd on all interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service.d
           └─wait.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2022-07-15 12:30:09 BST; 13min ago
  Process: 381 ExecStart=/usr/lib/dhcpcd5/dhcpcd -q -w (code=exited, status=6)

Jul 15 12:30:09 worker7 systemd[1]: Starting dhcpcd on all interfaces...
Jul 15 12:30:09 worker7 dhcpcd[381]: Not running dhcpcd because /etc/network/interfaces
Jul 15 12:30:09 worker7 dhcpcd[381]: defines some interfaces that will use a
Jul 15 12:30:09 worker7 dhcpcd[381]: DHCP client or static address
Jul 15 12:30:09 worker7 systemd[1]: dhcpcd.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=6/NOTCONFIGURED
Jul 15 12:30:09 worker7 systemd[1]: dhcpcd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 15 12:30:09 worker7 systemd[1]: Failed to start dhcpcd on all interfaces.
```

Thanks for providing the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you put dhcp in interfaces you break dhcpcd as indicated in the error message.

```
: Starting dhcpcd on all interfaces...
: Not running dhcpcd because /etc/network/interfaces
: defines some interfaces that will use a
: DHCP client or static address
```

You can only have one DHCP client.

This will then fall back to Debian networking, which only allows a single DHCP interface.

It is unclear what you think the stuff you put in dhcpcd.conf will do.

NOTE Linux does not use \ in paths.

Comment: I follow the steps from a Youtube video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHVEwCEIzm4). It's the only work solution after I try so many different suggestions.

Comment: "It's the only work solution" BUT it doesn't work - which is presumably why you asked. Following random Youtube videos (which are obviously wrong) is a poor strategy.